# JQuery/HTML Input Tag to allow device users to choose between photo and video

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to create an application where a user can click on a button to take a photo or video. Here is my input tag.

```
<input type="file" name="inp_file" id="inp_file"
               accept="image/.jpg,video/quicktime,video/mp4"
               capture="environment"
               class="form-control input-lg"
               onchange="sendFile()" />
```

When the user clicks on a button, the button does some input validation and runs this piece of code if everything checks out `$('#inp_file').click();`.

When testing the site with an iPod, the iPod only allows the user to use the video. Is there a way for the user to switch between taking a video or photo? Or do I have to create separate input tags for each photo and video?